# Custom terminal command with argparse and .profile

Tags: python, bash, command-line, argparse, url-shortener

I'm trying to create a command line interface for the [dft.ba URL shortener](http://dft.ba/dev/if.py?show=documentation) using python's argparse and a function in .profile which calls my python script. This is the business end of the code in my python script:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shortens URLs with dft.ba')
parser.add_argument('LongURL',help='Custom string at the end of the shortened URL')
parser.add_argument('--source','-s',help='Custom string at the end of the shortened URL')
parser.add_argument('-c','--copy', action="store_true", default=False, help='Copy the shortened URL to the clipboard')
parser.add_argument('-q','--quiet', action="store_true", default=False, help="Execute without printing")
args = parser.parse_args()
target_url=args.LongURL
source=args.source
print source


query_params={'auth':'ip','target':target_url,'format':'json','src':source}
shorten='http://dft.ba/api/shorten'
response=requests.get(shorten,params=query_params)
data=json.loads(response.content)
shortened_url=data['response']['URL']
print data
print args.quiet
print args.copy

if data['error']:
    print 'Error:',data['errorinfo']['extended']
elif not args.copy:
    if args.quiet:
        print "Error: Can't execute quietly without copy flag"
    print 'Link:',shortened_url
else:
    if not args.quiet:
        print 'Link:',shortened_url
        print 'Link copied to clipboard'
    setClipboardData(shortened_url)
```

and then in .profile I have this:

```
dftba(){
    cd ~/documents/scripts
    python dftba.py "$1" 
}
```

running `dftba SomeURL` will spit a shortened URL back at me, but none of the options work.When I try to use `-s SomeSource` before the LongURL, it gives `error: argument --source/-s: expected one argument`, when used afterwards it does nothing and when omitted gives `error: too few arguments`. `-c` and `-q` give `error: too few arguments` for some reason. The copy to clipboard function I'm using works perfectly fine if I force copying, however.

I'm very much feeling my way through this, so I'm sorry if I've made some glaringly obvious mistake. I get the feeling the problem's in my bash script, I just don't know where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets just focus on what the parser does

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shortens URLs with dft.ba')
parser.add_argument('LongURL',help='Custom string at the end of the shortened URL')
parser.add_argument('--source','-s',help='Custom string at the end of the shortened URL')
parser.add_argument('-c','--copy', action="store_true", default=False, help='Copy the shortened URL to the clipboard')
parser.add_argument('-q','--quiet', action="store_true", default=False, help="Execute without printing")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args  # add to debug the `argparse` behavior
```

`LongURL` is a positional argument that is always required.  If missing you'll get the 'too few arguments' error message.

`source` is optional, but when provided must include an argument.  If not given `args.source is None`.  As written the `source` argument must be given in ADDITION to the `LongURL` one.

Both `args.copy` and `args.quiet` are booleans; default value is `False`; and `True` if given.  (the `default=False` parameter is not needed.)

I haven't tried to work through the logic using `copy` and `quiet`.  That won't come into play if there are problems earlier with `LongURL` and `source`.

Compare these samples:

```
In [38]: parser.parse_args('one'.split())
Out[38]: Namespace(LongURL='one', copy=False, quiet=False, source=None)

In [41]: parser.parse_args('-s one two -c -q'.split())
Out[41]: Namespace(LongURL='two', copy=True, quiet=True, source='one')
```

It may also help to look at what `parse_args` is parsing: `sys.argv[1:]` (if you have doubts about what you are getting from .profile).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason I omitted the fact that I was actually putting a  source after `-s`, so the input was `dftba -s SOURCE LongURL`. It still gives `error: argument --source/-s: expected one argument`. In that instance it never gets to `print args`, so I can't tell what's going on there. Trying `-c` and `-q` gives `error: too few arguments`, again not printing `args`. Sorry this wasn't all in the post, brain was a bit mashed when I wrote it.

Comment: Check 'sys.argv'.  ‘"$1"‘ may be giving one .string.

Comment: Aha! I thought it might be this. When I run `dftba -q URL`,sys.argv is [dftba.py,'-q']. When I add "$2" to .profile, it executes properly (it errors, but it's meant to do that). After a bit of a look around, "$@" seems to do what I need. That being said, while `-s SOURCE` doesn't cause an error, it doesn't actually _work_. I must be misunderstanding the API's docs. Thanks for the help. How should I mark this as solved?

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm such a pillock. It does say `shorten(POST)`, at least I know what _that_ means now. Makes sense it'd be a POST, thinking about it. Thanks so much for the help. Any chance you know if/how I could distribute this as an 'installable' thing now I have it running properly?